# How to get unique members of object class (groupofUniqueNames) from an ldap server using java

Tags: java, ldap

I'm developing an application with ldap server using java. Here i want to get all unique members of object class (groupofUniqueNames) from an ldap server.

Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code

```
String[] attrIDs = { Constants.UNIQUEMEMBER };
            Attributes answer = iniDirContext.getAttributes("cn=project,dn=aibl,dc=net", attrIDs);

            NamingEnumeration namingEnumeration = answer.getAll();
            Attribute attr = (Attribute) namingEnumeration.next();

            for (NamingEnumeration namingEnumeration1 = attr.getAll(); namingEnumeration1
                    .hasMore();) {

                String str = namingEnumeration1.next().toString();}
```